# pyjq error while trying to split line to select the last word

Tags: python, json, jq

I am trying to cut the last word of a json key value using `.split()[-1]` with pyjq, but failing with error: `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '('`

> The key/value - "subject": "The user has user id: 2432343f3f-34kfert-343mn5788886"

The JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": "The user has user id: 76e195fa-67f1-4ea6-bb0e-29c123855978",
        "date": "2018-11-01T08:41:53Z"
    },
    {
        "id": "The user has user id: 195fa76e-67f1-4ea6-bb0e-5597829c1238",
        "date": "2018-10-31T14:43:04Z"
    }
]

response_read = open('my.json', 'r')
response_read_parsed = json.loads(response_read.read())
rule = pyjq.all('.value[] | { "id": .["subject"].split()[-1], "date": .receivedDateTime }', response_read_parsed)
```

But this approach works if i write without pyjq

```
myid= (response_read_parsed['subject'].split()[-1])
print json.dumps(myid, indent=4)
```

As there are multiple entries like above, i decided to filter using pyjq.

Is there any mistake i have done? i am not able to figure it out still. Please help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jq's `split` requires an argument, which must be a valid JSON string. In your case, you might want to use `splits` instead as it takes a regular expression argument.  However, `splits` produces a stream, so you would presumably want to write something along the lines of:

```
.value[]
| { "id": [.["subject"] | splits("  *")][-1],
    "date": .receivedDateTime }
```

Comment: This has error still @peak. `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '('`

Comment: Whoops! Fixed. I copied your pythonic syntax :-(